# How to configure a search box in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to put a search box in my home.blade but it is not working properly.

Here bellow is my home view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <form action="{{ route('home') }}">

        <div class="p-1 bg-light rounded rounded-pill shadow-sm mb-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Here the animal serial number..." aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control border-0 bg-light">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="button-addon1" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    @foreach($animal as $animal)
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3>Details for the animal</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $animal->id }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Animal: </strong>{{ $animal->type->category }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{ $animal->gender }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Place Of Birth: </strong>{{ $animal->user->address->city }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Farm: </strong>{{ $animal->user->name }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ $animal->created_at }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach
    @if(request()->has('search') && request()->get('search') != '')
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3>Details for the animal</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $animal->id }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Animal: </strong>{{ $animal->type->category }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{ $animal->gender }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Place Of Birth: </strong>{{ $animal->user->address->city }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Farm: </strong>{{ $animal->user->name }}</p>
                                <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ $animal->created_at }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endif
@endsection
```

and my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $animal =Animal::all();
    if (request()->has('search') && request()->get('search') != ''){
        $animal = $animal->where('serial_number', 'like', "%" .request()->get('search')."%");
    }
    return view('home', compact('animal'))->with('message', 'Below is the result');
}
```

It bringing me an error like this 
'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/resources/views/home.blade.php)'
meaning the animal I have passed in my controller is not worrking.

Comment: I assume your animal model actually has an Id in the table?

Comment: If an animal is searched, am I correct in assuming that you only want to show the one animal on the page and not have the foreach?

Comment: Yes that what i wanted but it seems like my search was not working

Comment: Are you using the `show()` method in this controller?

Comment: Oh no am using the index

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems to work through.

1) You have a variable name collision -

```
@foreach($animal as $animal)
```

This will overwrite your collection of animals (`$animal`) with the first individual animal in that collection.  On the next iteration `foreach` will try to iterate over each element of that single `animal`.  And those elements (like `id`) don't themselves have properties like `id`, so you get the error you are seeing.

You should change your variable names to avoid the collision, for example convention would be to use `$animals`, plural, to indicate it is a collection of more than one.  So:

**Controller**

```
$animals = Animal::all();
// ...
return view('home', compact('animals')) ...
```

**View**

```
@foreach($animals as $animal)
```

2) The search code in your controller:

```
$animal = $animal->where(...);
```

does not actually `get` the results.  You need to append `get()`, [as shown in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models):

```
$animal = $animal->where(...)->get();
```

3) As @Rwd pointed out in the comments, your view has 2 separate chunks of content, one which looks like it should display a collection of `animals` (the top one with `foreach`), and a second which looks like it should display just the search results.  Similar to problem 1 above, you have a name collision here - both sections are using `$animal`.  After the `foreach` loop has finished, `$animal` is the last animal in the collection of all animals - not your search result.

If I am understanding correctly, you probably want use 2 separate variable names, maybe `$animals` at the top to list all `animals`, and then maybe `$result` to show a single search result.

If that is true, you need to update as follows:

**Controller**

```
// For the top list of all animals
$animals = Animal::all();

// For the single search result
$result = false;
if (request()->has('search') && request()->get('search') != ''){
    $result = $animal->where(...)->get();
}

// Return them both, separately
return view('home', ['animals' => $animals, 'result' => $result])...;
```

**View**

```
@foreach($animals as $animal)

// ...

@if($result)
    {{ $result->id }}
```

Comment: It looks like when the search functionality is used it's only meant to use the one animal so this would work for the foreach but not for the block underneath it.

Comment: Yeah Of course it is working for the animals but the search still not working

Comment: @Rwd you're right. And in fact the search code in the controller won't work either.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: still on problem with the '$animal' which is not define in the controller

Comment: C'mon @Jimmyjbk try a little harder! :-) Debug it! What happens when you `return $animal;` from your controller, instead of the view? If that works, you know your query is working.  Also, it sounds like a new problem right, not the one in your original question? New problems usually mean you are making progress, solving one thing at a time.

Comment: Yes It is a new problem

Comment: @Jimmyjbk what is `$animal` supposed to be now? In 3) above I suggested using `$result` for your search, instead of `$animal`.  Are you still using `$animal`? If yes, that won't work, as I describe in 3).

Comment: for the line of result line in the controller, I even changed it to animals but still could not work

Comment: I am not sure what you mean now. Are you using the code I suggested in 3) in my answer? If yes, which line is giving you an error?